# Url rewriter in ASP.NET: Resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the url rewriter described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx).

On production, it works great but locally, for any links that uses url rewrite, it says:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Do you have any idea why?
Do I have to install IIS locally and configure something?

Some rules I use:

```
<RewriterConfig>
<Rules>
  <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>/Payment/Secure/Order.htm</LookFor>
    <SendTo>/Payment/Secure/Order.htm</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
  <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>/Payment/Secure/Result.htm</LookFor>
    <SendTo>/Payment/Secure/Result.htm</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
  <RewriterRule>
```

..

They are all defined well because they work in production...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you using WebDevServer locally? Because generally it runs on localhost:PORT/ProjectName/, making that application root is in /ProjectName/ and not /

Comment: Yes, but I changed virtual path to '/' so the links do not contain the ProjectName..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally, Url rewrite only works with IIS running on localhost for your website!

Answer (score 0):

Yes specify the correct path name for your web server.